# how to save default value in an array from uipickerview when the picker is not touched

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a view in which i have added `Labels` and buttons such that the matter is typed in `Label` and on clicking the `button` corresponding to the label a tableview appears. And in that table there are `pickerviews` in each `tableviewcell`. The `pickerview` contains numbers from 0 to 5 to rate the operations in various aspects which are typaed in the text fields. In this way there are multiple `tableviews` and `pickers` in each of them. I want the value selected that is between 0 and 5 to be saved in an array. And when the picker is not touched I want the default value in the corresponding untouched picker to be saved in the array.

Hope you understood my need. Please do help me to solve this.

Thank you.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    cln_total+=row;
    self.cln_label_total.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cln_total];
    NSLog(@"cln_total is  %d",cln_total);
    QSCEAppDelegate* qsceObj=(QSCEAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSLog(@"row is %d",row);
    qsceObj.temp=qsceObj.temp+row;
    NSLog(@"temp @ didselectrow is %d",qsceObj.temp);
    [qsceObj.selectednums_second addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row]];
    NSLog(@"qsceObj.selectednums_second %@",qsceObj.selectednums_second);
    NSLog(@"qsceObj.app_city %@",qsceObj.app_city);
    value=row;
    NSLog(@"value in didselectrow in picker is %d",value);
    NSLog(@"qsceObj.picview_sec %@",qsceObj.picView_sec);

 }
```

This my `didDisappear` function

```
   -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{ QSCEAppDelegate*myAppdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

   for(i=0;i<=44;i++)
    {
    int r=[myAppdelegate.picView_sec selectedRowInComponent:0];
   NSLog(@"r %d is %d",i,r);
    if([myAppdelegate.picView_sec selectedRowInComponent:0]==-1)
    {
        [myAppdelegate.selectednums_second addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }
    else
    {
       [myAppdelegate.selectednums_second addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[myAppdelegate.picView_sec selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    }
     NSLog(@"myAppdelegate.selectednums_second is%@",myAppdelegate.selectednums_second);
  }
}
```

Comment: show how you are doing in - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

Comment: okay...I'll put it here..                                            -

Comment: actually i have added the comments to save the values from pickerview in diddisappear function

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you what i did for getting the default value

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* _jsonDictionary; // this is array to show the values
```

in viewDidLoad i have init the array with dictionary

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    NSArray *keys = @[@"UserId",@"PreferenceId",@"NumericValue",@"StringValue",@"BooleanValue"                     ];
    NSArray *objects = @[@(userId), @(row + 1), @(1),  @"", @0];
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
    [_jsonDictionary insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys] atIndex:row];
}
```

and in

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSArray *keys = @[@"UserId",@"PreferenceId",@"NumericValue",@"StringValue",@"BooleanValue"                     ];
    NSArray *objects = nil;
    switch (_pickerSelectedIndex.row) {
        case 0:
            objects = @[@([userInfo.userId intValue]), @(_pickerSelectedIndex.row + 1), @(row + 1), @"", @0];
            if([_jsonDictionary safeObjectAtIndex:0] != nil) {
                [_jsonDictionary removeObjectAtIndex:0];}
            [_jsonDictionary insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys] atIndex:0];
            break;
        case 1:
            objects = @[@([userInfo.userId intValue]), @(_pickerSelectedIndex.row + 1), @(row + 1), @"", @0];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row] forKey:@"GenderPrefrence"];
            if([_jsonDictionary safeObjectAtIndex:1] != nil) {
                [_jsonDictionary removeObjectAtIndex:1]; }
            [_jsonDictionary insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys] atIndex:1];
            break;
        case 2:
            objects = @[@([userInfo.userId intValue]), @(_pickerSelectedIndex.row + 1), @(row + 1), @"", @0];
            if([_jsonDictionary safeObjectAtIndex:2] != nil) {
                [_jsonDictionary removeObjectAtIndex:2]; }
            [_jsonDictionary insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys] atIndex:2];
            break;
    }
}
```

That worked for me hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for replying ... nyways let me try it..hope it will wrk for me too... :)

Comment: I my viewDidDisappear function i have written the code to save the selected values from picker to the array... But the problem is when I log the array...I get all the selected values but the default value which is 0 appears after all the selected values. I want the default value to be saved in the same order not after all selected values.Do anyone have idea on how to do this.                                  Thank you....

Comment: You should set the value at didSelectDelegate not at vewDidDisappear

Comment: but when i do it in didselect delegate only when the picker is selected then only the value will be saved to the array. If Iam wrong do correct me..k.

Comment: Yes, initially you have the default value in array and when user update any your new value get update into array, so there will be no issue